# Insert data into database manually inside a laravel 5 controller without a form

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I need to insert some data into a sqlite database, manually inside a (Laravel 5) controller and without a form.

I've tried with this methods:

1st:

```
DB::insert('insert into cars values (?, ?, ?)', [1, "Infinity", "MS500"]);
```

2nd:

```
Car::create([
    'brand' => 'Infinity',
    'model' => 'MS500',
]);
```

3rd:

```
$car = new Car();
$car->setAttribute('brand', 'Infinity');
$car->setAttribute('model', 'MS500');
$car->save();
```

The **1st** method works, but I need to insert thousand of rows, and **the time and performance is not so good.**

The **2nd** and **3rd** methods give me this error:

```
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(), called in /var/www/html/AppLaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php on line 525 and defined
```

I don't know what means this error, I have found a lot about it, and about to populate the data into the database manually, with no results.

This is the model class:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = null;
    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    protected $fillable = ['brand', 'model'];
}
```

This is the migration class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCarsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->text('model');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cars');
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I've tested with the bulk insertion too:

4th

```
$arr = [
    [
        'brand' => 'Infinity',
        'model' => 'MS500',
    ],
    [
        'brand' => 'Toyota',
        'model' => 'LK2500',
    ],
];

DB::insert($arr);
```

... but I got this new error:

```
 ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion
```

Comment: in your 3rd method, why not just access the `Model`s attribute directly? E.g., `$car->brand = 'Infinity';`.

Comment: @Wreigh I've tried whit it too, without results.

Comment: I'm confused on your first method. What metrics did you use to measure performance? It's a straight insert so performance should be a non factor.

Comment: As an aside, `$table->text('model');` should be a string also. Is model ever going to exceed 255 charaxters?

Comment: @btl yes, it is possible that `model` can exceed 255 characters. I changed `test` for `string` and the same result. I'm not using a tool to measure the performance, but for my the high delay on the browser is enough to change the method (more than 3 minutes for 4000 insertions). I have done this kind of thing with Symfony2+ and it execute the tasks very fast.

Comment: Are you inserting one record at a time? DB:insert also accepts an array for bulk insertion, it is much faster.

Comment: @btl look the edit of my question, I've tested the bulk insertion, but I got a new error!

Comment: Which Laravel version do you have installed? You can check it in the `composer.lock` file.

Comment: @Camilo I'm using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an extensive array of arrays with the data (let's say 10000 rows):

```
$arr = [
    [
        'brand' => 'Infinity',
        'model' => 'MS500',
    ],
    [
        'brand' => 'Toyota',
        'model' => 'LK2500',
    ],
    ...
    // 10000 rows
];
```

I separated the amount of data to insert in chunks of 500, and I inserted into the database inside of transactions.

```
$div = 500;

for ($i = 0; $i < intdiv(count($arr), $div); $i++) {

    $new_arr = [];

    for ($j = ($i * $div); $j < (($i + 1) * $div); $j++) {
        $new_arr[] = $arr[$j];
    }

    DB::transaction(function () use ($new_arr) {
        DB::table('hotels')->insert($new_arr);
    });
}
```

I've done this task of this way because SQLite restrict the amount of insertions at the same time. the performance and the speed with this solution is very high.

**Edit**

For all you collection fans:

```
collect($arr)->chunk(500)->each(function ($chunk) { 
    DB::transaction(function () use ($chunk) {
        DB::table('hotels')->insert($chunk->toArray());
    });
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your PHP version? I think the code you wrote should work.

try with this

```
$car = new Car;
$car->brand = 'Infinity';
$car->model = 'MS500';
$car->save();
```

=============================

EDIT:
I googled for this and found someone had similar issue. Simply it is a problem with Laravel installation.
https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth/issues/29

Comment: That code produce the same error. Also I have executed `composer update` and I've got the same error with all this methods. My PHP version is `PHP 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

Comment: try to remove whole vendor directory and reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: Done, same result. I've cleared the composer cache and nothing!

Answer (score 0):

```
$Car= new App\Car;
$options = $Car->options;
$options['brand'] = 'value';
$options['model'] = 'value';
$Car->options = $options;
$Car->save();
```

it must work