# Processing thousands of records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

A bit of a background about the problem:

The company I work for provides a similar service to that of Booking.com/Airbnb etc. Property Owners list their properties on the site and they get bookings in return.

At the end of the month, I have to generate invoices and send to these properties. To generate these invoices, I use records from far back as April 01st 2018. For a particular property, I search for its relevant bookings and then iterate through the result set to calculate our commission due.

As the company grew, the number of properties and bookings also increased. There are now more than 100 properties and some of these properties have more than 2000 bookings. To generate even one invoice it takes a significantly long time, more than a minute most times.

I want to know the best practice in processing large result sets such as this because I feel the current implementation is inefficient.

The only thing I can think of doing is to calculate all the amounts due for each property and write it to a separate table and then just amend that amount each time a booking is made. Then I could just use the amount in that table to get the dues owed at the end of a month. But I dont feel that is correct either as its usually best practice to not keep derived attributes in the DB.

I use PHP server side, Laravel 5.4 and MySQL 5.7 is the DBMS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

PS: I have also tried using the `chunk` method available on PHP Collections but they did not offer a significant reduction in time.

EDIT: I missed out a pretty important part. When debugging I can clearly see that the most time is spent on the calculations/processing the thousands of records. Not the query itself. The records are fetched in less than 10 seconds even with bad internet and most times less than 5 seconds. I would show the code but its at my work machine and I do not have access to it at the moment. Its something I was mulling over at home. Basically the code is something like this:

```
$properties = Property::where('status', 'Active');
foreach($properties as $property) { // 100+ times
     $bookings = Booking::where('status', 'Approved')->where('checked_in', 1)->where('propId', $property->id)->get();
     $commission = 0.0; // commissions owed to us
     $commissionOta = 0.0; // any commissions owed to OTA's
     foreach($bookings as $booking) { // 2000+ times
          $commission += $booking->commission;
          $commissionOta += $booking->commissionOta;
     }
     $totalReceived = PaymentReceived::where('propId', $property->id)->sum('amount'); // any amounts paid by the property owner
     $property->payable = ($commission + $commissionOta) - $totalReceived;
}
```

Comment: If you know the date at which you have to get the commisions then create a commision table and calculate from start date to end date and grab values and add them together from the commisions table then create you a widget so that you can see the value returned therefor your website is doing all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: You may want to make sure you have the proper indexing on the tables, which will help speed up queries significantly.

Comment: 200,000 results? This is a tiny result set! The 'iterating' part sounds like the bottleneck.

Comment: @JosephWilliamson there sort of isnt a website to do the heavy lifting cuz all this happens when generating the invoice and emailing it to the client. I compile the data and generate a PDF invoice using it.

Comment: 1) 200k records is definitely not big data. Not even rare to have lot bigger datasets. 2) It is difficult to give more specific advice than to "create an efficient data structure, add relevant indexes, and configure your MySQL properly". Why? Because your question lacks details. You need to identify what slows down the invoice generation. Is it the query? Is it the php code? Something else? When you identified your bottleneck, then you can provide the relevant code with supporting information (e.g. if your db query is slow, then provide the output of explain with table structure and indexes).

Comment: @aynber wouldnt that just speed up the querying process? Cuz when I debug the process, the records are fetched in less than 10 seconds most times. Most of the time is spent during the processing/calculations

Comment: Well then maybe its time to change that what you are describing is something a server can and SHOULD handle humans make mistakes well coded machines do not :)

Comment: To further assist im going to need to see some code otherwise theres not much I can do but speculate

Comment: Incidentally, if a property was booked even just once per day every day since April 1st 2018, it would be fully booked until September 2023. Are you renting rooms by the hour?

Comment: If you were talking about **millions** of rows, yeah, that could be slow. But thousands? Seriously... with proper indexes that should be blazing fast. Can you identify and show the slowest query?

Comment: If you're retrieving rows in 10 seconds, you can try seeing if there's any processing you can pass off to the database instead of via code, such as count and sum.

Comment: Hoping the code in the new edit would help out a bit. Its not the exact code especially the query has more `WHERE` clauses but I feel the iteration is the bottleneck and this is what basically happens during the iteration @Shadow @JosephWilliamson

Comment: @Strawberry Most properties have 50+ rooms......unfortunately

Comment: Review this question and its answer, maybe it could help you to achieve your goal https://stackoverflow.com/a/48576552/6107280

Comment: Have you considered using `->sum(...)` instead of the loop? Because that's what basically your loop does.

Comment: To be honest, the whole thing can probably be done with a couple of joins and sums in sql, which is optimised for such quick calculations.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are asking for. 
But in general what I would strongly recommend is to avoid querying in the loop:

So all that your code fragment:

```
$properties = Property::where('status', 'Active');
foreach($properties as $property) { // 100+ times
     $bookings = Booking::where('status', 'Approved')->where('checked_in', 1)->where('propId', $property->id)->get();
     $commission = 0.0; // commissions owed to us
     $commissionOta = 0.0; // any commissions owed to OTA's
     foreach($bookings as $booking) { // 2000+ times
          $commission += $booking->commission;
          $commissionOta += $booking->commissionOta;
     }
     $totalReceived = PaymentReceived::where('propId', $property->id)->sum('amount'); // any amounts paid by the property owner
     $property->payable = ($commission + $commissionOta) - $totalReceived;
}
```

Seem to be equal to just this query:

```
SELECT p.id,
       SUM(b.commission) s_comm,
       SUM(b.commissionOta) s_commOta,
       SUM(b.commission) + SUM(b.commissionOta) - pr.amount payable
FROM Property p
INNER JOIN Booking b
ON b.propOd = p.id
  AND b.status = 'Approved'
  AND checked_in = 1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pr.propId, SUM(pr.amount) amount
    FROM PaymentReceived pr
    GROUP BY pr.propId
) pr
ON pr.propId = p.id
WHERE p.status = 'Active'
GROUP BY p.id
```

Try to run this query. Check the result set and performance and try to adapt your code to use one query instead of looping DB requests.

For Laravel it should be something like:

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT p.id,
       SUM(b.commission) s_comm,
       SUM(b.commissionOta) s_commOta,
       SUM(b.commission) + SUM(b.commissionOta) - pr.amount payable
FROM Property p
INNER JOIN Booking b
ON b.propOd = p.id
  AND b.status = \'Approved\'
  AND checked_in = 1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pr.propId, SUM(pr.amount) amount
    FROM PaymentReceived pr
    GROUP BY pr.propId
) pr
ON pr.propId = p.id
WHERE p.status = \'Active\'
GROUP BY p.id');

foreach($result as $r){
    echo 'Property id: '.$r->id.' Commission: '.$r->s_comm. ' Commission Ota: '.$r->commissionOta .' Payable: '.$r->payable ;
}
```

Another idea you should try to implement is to **cut/close the period**. Right now if I understand correctly you are recalculating all the data from the very beginning of the time every month or some other period. But usually you should have some balanced results stored from previous period and recalculate only the difference base on last period data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have some experience with "big data" (well, not so big but not small - I am developing in telecommunications, and I have a call details table that frequently exceeds 200k records). I can tell you that with proper indexing the searches are quite fast. I just did a test in a table with 116803 rows on a non indexed column and got the result:

```
Showing rows 0 - 24 (1608 total, Query took 0.0016 seconds)
```

Now, on the same table, on an indexed column:

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds.)
```

Also, if you use joins (left, right, inner etc) have them on indexed columns. In this way sql does not have to search the whole joined table, for each row.

So, if you have the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON column_from_a = column_from_b
```

make sure that `column_from_b` is indexed, if table_b is quite large.

Another thing (but a little more complicated) is replication. You can have a sql cluster with, lets say 3 servers. You can set up the main applications to use 2 of them and have the 3'rd one reserved for some intensive operation.

But the best solution is to see how you can have your custom solution for your specific type of operations. There is no general recipe that can be implemented everywhere.

Comment: Apart from the fact that MySQL should be able to handle such amount of data easily, your answer does not really add much to the conversation. It definitely does not answer the question of how to make this faster. As per the comment by the OP, it is not the sql part that is slow, it is the php code.